# how to get the value of parent select with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a sample output, I want to get the value of the parent select option,

```
  <ul>
     <li> 
         <select class='cbo'><option value='1' selected>1</option></select>
         <ul>
             <li>
                <select class='cbo'><option value='2' selected>2</option></select>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>



  <script>
         $('.cbo').on('change', function(){
                 var current_val = $(this).find(':selected').val();
                 var parrent_val = $(this).parent().parent().parent()
                                      .find(':selected').val();
                   console.log('parent: '+parent_val' current'+current_val);
         })
    </script>
```

the result i get is ( parent_val = 2, and current_val = 2 )
i should get a value of 1 for the parent_val

Comment: you could add "name" or "id" attribute for both select elements and access it easily instead of chaining multiple parent() methods...

Comment: use closest('select') instead of parent().parent().parent()

Comment: you have a syntax error in your code.  console.log('parent: '+parent_val' current'+current_val); it should be  console.log('parent: '+parent_val+' current'+current_val);

Comment: Do you have other `.cbo` elements on the page? Or just these two?

Comment: Your code is working for me except `parrent_val` wrong and missing `+` in console

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use `closest` to navigate to the `ul` and then `siblings` to get the `select`. I'd also use `val` to get the value.

```
$('.cbo').on('change', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var current_val = $this.val();
    var parent_val = $this.closest("ul").siblings("select").val();
    console.log('parent: ' + parent_val + ' current' + current_val);
});
```

Note that you'll get `undefined` for the parent value if you change the value of one of the top-level `selects`, since `siblings("select")` doesn't match anything.

Example:

```js
$('.cbo').on('change', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var current_val = $this.val();
    var parent_val = $this.closest("ul").siblings("select").val();
    console.log('parent: ' + parent_val + ' current' + current_val);
});
```

```html
<ul>
 <li> 
     <select class='cbo'>
        <option value='1' selected>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
    </select>
     <ul>
         <li>
            <select class='cbo'>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='2' selected>2</option>
                <option value='3'>3</option>
                <option value='4'>4</option>
            </select>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li> 
     <select class='cbo'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2' selected>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
    </select>
     <ul>
         <li>
            <select class='cbo'>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='2' selected>2</option>
                <option value='3'>3</option>
                <option value='4'>4</option>
            </select>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </li>
 <li> 
     <select class='cbo'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3' selected>3</option>
        <option value='4'>4</option>
    </select>
     <ul>
         <li>
            <select class='cbo'>
                <option value='1'>1</option>
                <option value='2' selected>2</option>
                <option value='3'>3</option>
                <option value='4'>4</option>
            </select>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are missing + in console.log('parent: '+parent_val+' current'+current_val);

Comment: @Dinesh: Thanks -- I noticed when doing the snippet, it's one of several typos in the question.

Comment: what if i have another <ul> tag after the <select> tag,

Comment: @apelidoko: Define "after" -- as a following sibling? As a descendant? As a descendant of a following sibling? If you do have something other than what's in your question, please show it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.cbo').on('change', function() {
  var current_val = $('option:selected',this).val();
  var parrent_val = $(this).closest('ul').prev('select.cbo').find('option:selected').val();
  console.log('parent: ' + parrent_val+ ' current' + current_val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <select class='cbo'><option value='1' selected>1</option><option value='2' >2</option></select>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <select class='cbo'><option value='1' >1</option><option value='2' selected>2</option></select>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  
  <li>
    <select class='cbo'><option value='3' selected>3</option><option value='4' >4</option></select>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <select class='cbo'><option value='3' >3</option><option value='4' selected>4</option></select>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Use this context to get the current select
2. Use `.closest()` then use `.prev()` to get the parent select

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just notice change solution to using this and `.not()`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder update will get the parent ul that is sibling of select but it will get undefined if the change will happened in the parent select nothing i can do that is the html mark up

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is not the same as your answer now because i am using .prev() as suggestion